# continuous functions inequality

Tags: functions, continuity

Let f:R$\rightarrow$R be a continuous function such that rfor any two two real numbers x and y,$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq7|x-y|^{201}$$.Then
which one is true $$(A)f(101)=f(202)+8$$.$$(B)f(101)=f(201)+1$$.$$(C)f(101)=f(200)+2$$.(D)None of these.please explain.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition with index grater than 1 hence $f$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|^{201}$ for all $x,y$.

(D) is the correct option.